# AngularJS Scope is not accessible through console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

I just started learning angular js. I have understanding that we can access and debug scope available to any dom element by selecting/inspecting anywhere on the page and running

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

code on console. But if you try this, I find its value `undefined`. How they are hiding it and how can I reach to data through console?

Comment: Load `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`. You will get better stack traces and data debugging will be enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its likley that `debugInfoEnabled` in `$compileProvider` is set to false, which means `angular.element($0).scope()` will always return `undefined`

You can however run `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo` in the console which will override this.

Reference:

[AngularJS $compileProvider Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#debugInfoEnabled)

[AngularJS reloadWithDebugInfo Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.reloadWithDebugInfo)

Comment: angular.reloadWithDebugInfo is a life-saver if you don't have access to the source files  ! thanks for the tip 

Answer (score 0):

Load `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`. You will get better stack traces and data debugging will be enabled.

From the Docs:

> ## angular.element — jQuery/jqLite Extras
>
> AngularJS also provides the following additional methods and events to both jQuery and jqLite:
>
> - `scope()` - retrieves the [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) of the current element or its parent. **Requires [Debug Data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data)** to be enabled.
>
> — [AngularJS angular.element API Reference - jQuery/jqLite Extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $compileProvider API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#debugInfoEnabled)
- [AngularJS angular.reloadWithDebugInfo API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.reloadWithDebugInfo)